# Why my code doesn't work the else statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

Can anybody help me with my code.
I wrote a little program just so that I can learn some of the functions and what is going on.
Let me show you my code.

```
print "Hello student need help multiplying by any mutiplicaton"
student = raw_input("If so then tell me which ones? => ").lower()
for i in range(0, 11):
    if student == str(0):
       i_num = 0 * i
       print "0 times %d equals %d" % (i,i_num)
    elif student == str(10):
       i_num = 1 * 1
       print "1 times %d equals %d" % (i,i_num)
else:
    print "Try this program when you can't figure it out your multiplications."
```

if the student inputs something that doesnt pertain to the if statement it will print the else. But if the student inputs str(1) it prints the multiplication and also it prints the else which that is the problem of my code that I don't want to happend. Can anyone help me.
I am just trying to learn this functionality of if and elif and all that.

Comment: If you want to the else to be associated with the `if` block, it's indentation needs to align with that block.

Comment: There are severe syntax problems in your code: a missing `)` after `str(10` or the wrong indentation level for the `else:`

Comment: I'm sorry, "0 times %d equals %d"? Are you sure? Also, I've got some commas for you, looks like you've run out of them. here you are ,,,,,,,,,,,,. Please use them wisely.
As of your problem, else with print "Try this program ..." relates to the for block and executes each time loop ends.

Comment: Why are you hardcoding the string conversion of a number? Why not just use `"0"`?

Comment: An `else` attached to a `for` doesn't execute each time the loop ends, it executes only once, after all iterations are done, and only if you didn't `break` out of the loop anywhere (or `return` or `raise`).

Comment: @J0HN: `"0 times %d equals %d"` is fine, because the first `%d` is `i`, and the second is `i_num`, which is `0 * i`. So, it'll print `0 times 3 equals 0`, etc. (The problem is in the next one, which will print `1 times 3 equals 1` because he's got `1 * 1` instead of `1 * i`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` is currently set to run on the successful completion of the `for` loop, look at the indentation. If you move it inside the loop everything works fine. Your code does contain some syntax errors though.

Fixed version of your program:

```
print "Hello student need help multiplying by any mutiplicaton"
student = raw_input("If so then tell me which ones? => ") # no need for lower()
for i in range(0, 11):
    if student == '0':
        i_num = 0 * i
        print "0 times %d equals %d" % (i,i_num)
    elif student == '1':
        i_num = 1 * 1
        print "1 times %d equals %d" % (i,i_num)
    else:
        print "Try this program when you can't figure it out your multiplications."
```

But multiplying is easy, so why not just do this:

```
print "Hello student need help multiplying by any mutiplicaton"
num = int(raw_input("If so then tell me which ones? => "))
for i in range(0, 11):
    print "%d times %d equals %d" % (num, i, i * num)
```

Comment: hey jamylak thanks for the help and the reason I did it like that is because I was reading this website that was talking about range and I saw him do that multiplying. Then I told my self lets get creative and practice on my logic skills with python and I came up with the first code. I know that your code is a lot simpler but the reason I decided to do the if statements is because I wanted the program to be interactive and talk back if the student decided to get smart about using something that is not a number like f! word or something

Answer (score 0):

you are missing an ) here:

```
elif student == str(10):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def isAnInt(s):
   try: 
      int(s)
      return True
   except ValueError:
    print "You must enter a number"


print "Hello student need help multiplying by any mutiplicaton"
student = raw_input("If so then tell me which ones? => ")
if(isAnInt(student)):
  number_to_calc = int(student)
  for i in range(0,11):
    i_num = number_to_calc * i
    print "%d times %d equals %d" % (number_to_calc, i, i_num)
```

Comment: I fix a little of your code but when i put like a word I get an error.

Comment: @user2270667 - I edited the code and actually tried it out this time.  I *thought* int(student) would fail and call the else: block if it was a string, but it actually raises an exception.  The new way I just laid out catches the exception and prints the statement.